# How to ensure that In-source Suppression is Not Included in Release Builds

Tags: c#

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview) article they recommend avoiding inclusion of suppressions like

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1039")]
```

in your release builds.

How is this accomplished (i.e. the suppression does its intended job, but it is not included in the release binaries)?

(context is Visual Studio 2017)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
#if DEBUG
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1039")]
#endif
```

The code between `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` will only be executed if you run your programm in debug mode.

So it will be excluded in release builds.